# Unable to access local docker container with IP address

Tags: docker, containers, ip-address

I am running a docker container locally on my Mac system. I have pasted the Dockerfile contents at the bottom of this post. I have exposed port 8888 in the image and I would like to access the python program from my host browser using container-ip-address:8888. But, it doesn't connect. Mapping it to a port on localhost works, but I don't want to do that. How can I solve this? (Already tried creating a docker network and running the container as part of the new network - no dice). Any help would be much appreciated.
Dockerfile contents -

```
FROM python:latest

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8888
RUN pip install tornado
CMD ["python", "./api.py" ]
```

Comment: On MacOS (and any non-Linux host) you don't have choice but to use a `docker run -p` published port: you cannot directly access the container-private IP address.  The `docker run -p` approach works on all host OSes (up to Docker running in a Docker Toolbox VM) and works the same way as non-Docker processes running on the same host.

Comment: Thank you. But this is a major issue for me since I am trying to call a Rest API exposed by the Python program. I am calling the API from a simple HTML page running locally on Tomcat. When I try to call the Rest API from the said HTML page, by connecting to the container via localhost, the browser (any browser) does not allow it due to a cross-referencing issue :-(. How do I test this then? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expose just tells docker that this container going to work with this port. it doesn't map it anywhere.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

Mapping is the task of code which is running your container. In case of local machine its a docker. If you don't map port in `docker run` then container will not be accessible from outside of docker network. At the same time your host machine is not in docker network. Same in case if you create docker network manually - your machine just doesn't have access to inner parts of it.

In other words you have to choose your way:

- use `-p ....` when you do docker run (local development)
- or define it in docker compose file if you use docker composer (mostly local development). this approach is very useful when you are running multiple communicating systems in docker.
- or do it through kubernetes yaml definition file on production if you go into kubernetes with your solution (production with orchestrator/ autoscaler and etc.)

Comment: Thank you. But this is a major issue for me since I am trying to call a Rest API exposed by the Python program. I am calling the API from a simple HTML page running locally on Tomcat. When I try to call the Rest API from the said HTML page, by connecting to the container via localhost, the browser (any browser) does not allow it due to a cross-referencing issue :-(. How do I test this then? Any thoughts?

Comment: are you talking about error `access-control-allow-origin` (i.e. CORS), caused by the fact that your javascript served from host machine (let say port 80), and api on some else port?
if yes then this issue is pretty common and can be easily solved by adding header in your api response:
 `Access-Control-Allow-Origin *` and  `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *`
here is doc:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods
just google how to wide open CORS on python api you are using, or worst case scenario it can be done though nginx proxy with those headers.

Comment: Thanks again! I haven't done that before and I am not able to find clear examples of how to do this. If I were to write a JS functon that is called on the click of a button in a HTML page and this JS function calls the rest api using xmlhttprequest or fetch, how would I include these headers? Example code would be awesome! Regards

Comment: CORS is implemented by browser. Basically when browser sees that your script does requests to the origin which doesn't match script origin (nlding protocol and port) - it starts with `OPTIONS` request toward destination your GET request will go (in your case it's python based API from what i understood) and reads response header. Response header must include `Access-Control-Allow-...` headers which defines hosts list where it can be requested from. if those headers has value `*` that means any host can do any method toward yourAPI. Which is good enough for dev environment.

Comment: You can try using something like Postman tool to do request toward your API, to see if it returns Access-Control-Allow headers. Because if you see CORS error that means that Access-Control-Allow didn't work.